# Can not fix error : No identities are available for signing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store

I got this error message when distributed app to App Store.

I tried to solve this problem follow tutorials step by step, but I still got same message.

Do you have any idea for solving it ?

Regards, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need a provisioning profile. And you need to configure Xcode's "Code Signing" in the build settings with the identity created.

I suggest you read Apple's guidelines for App Store submission clearly by creating an Apple account. Do some more googling for answers.